# Check for IIS Application exist or not by Appcmd

Tags: iis, msdeploy, appcmd

How can I Check the existence of Application in IIS.

Currently i am using

```
appcmd list app marketsworkflowdev/NonExistApp
```

But it is giving me details of it's parent site detail, if application doesn't exist on iis.

How can i check Whether an application is exist or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for

```
appcmd list app /site.name: marketsworkflowdev
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754776%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I just wanted to check whether a Application is exist or not.

Comment: It it is returned in the list it exists.

Comment: If it exists then %ERRORLEVEL% is set to 0, otherwise it's set to 1, which may be useful in a CMD script that checks to see whether the site exists